# Twilight Zone (TOS) Visual Riddle #1

Tags: riddle, visual

This puzzle suggests either an actor or a character from the original Twilight Zone.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to puzzling SE.  If/When someone gets one of your questions correct, be sure to mark it as correct, not just mention it in the comments!

Comment: Not sure how to mark it correct. I'm new here and still learning the ropes.

Comment: the help page for that is https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick Google search brings up

> Sgt. Mike Ferris, i.e. a mic and a Ferris wheel. I have no clue who this is nor have I watched that episode, but his name seems to fit this riddle. For those curious about the episode, it's entitled "Where is Everybody?" ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_Is_Everybody%3F)), originally broadcast in 1959, full of, it seems, archetypal last-man-on-earth TZ-vibes.

Comment: That's correct!